# Bootstrap menu hides

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, menu

I'm new using bootstrap and I have a problem implementing a bootstrap menu. It works perfectly until the screen become small and even it adjust the size and shows the 3 line menu, **it unfolds behind the next div so I cant see the options. It hides behind the next div which is a carousel** .

Thank you in advance.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row menu">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
  </div>

  </nav>

  <header class="themenu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MENU</a>
      
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Main <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              More
            </a>
            
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown ">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About us</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Story</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Others</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input id="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          
          <button class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center thecarousel">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-5">
    <div id="More" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="500px" alt="el1" />
          
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Pic1</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="500px" alt="el2" />
          
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Pic2</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="500px" alt="el3" />
          
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>pic3</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#More" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#More" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#More" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#More" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#More" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: A good editor (and even the snippet editor here) would make it apparent that you have HTML issues. There's a stray closing `nav` tag near the top, for one thing. And what's the empty `#menu` div for? Did you intentionally use the `row` class? There isn't one in the [navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/). [Image width attributes take unitless integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) as values (though fixed widths aren't conducive to responsive design anyway). Please format and validate your HTML as Step 1 of debugging any web page.

Comment: Yes, it is no doubt something to do with 2 x `collapse navbar-collpase` 1 of which is inside a `row` that has no closing `</div>`. The Navbar Docs link by Isherwood will serve you well. Have fun :)